# generate sinusoidal model with time varying frequency

Tags: matlab, signals, signal-processing

i would like  to create  sinusoidal time series with time varying frequencies like this . we have observation time from 2.93 second, from 0 to 1 second i want to create sinusoidal data in additive of white noise with one set of frequencies, while from 1 to 2.93  second another  set of frequencies, for this i wrote following code

```
 %   non stationary signal with time varying frequency
fs=100 ; % sampling frequency
ts=1/fs;
t=(0:ts:2.93);  % time vector 
%  i want to create   signal which consist of sinusoidal components in
%  addtiive of white noise ,  frequencies are defined in time as
x=25*sin(2*pi*23*t(t<1))+20*cos(2*pi*24*t(t<1))+24*sin(2*pi*22*t(t<1))+10*randn(size(t));
y=21*sin(2*pi*20*t(t>1))+26*cos(2*pi*17*t(t>1))+21*sin(2*pi*29*t(t>1))+10*randn(size(t));
z=[x';y'];
plot(t',z);
```

but it shows me error Error using  +

```
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in time_frequency (line 7)
x=25*sin(2*pi*23*t(t<1))+20*cos(2*pi*24*t(t<1))+24*sin(2*pi*22*t(t<1))+10*randn(size(t));
```

where i have  wrong dimension? also after fixing of this problem is think that code  corresponds to situation which i want right?thanks in advance

UPDATED :

```
%   non stationary signal with time varying frequency
fs=100 ; % sampling frequency
ts=1/fs;
t=(0:ts:2.93);  % time vector 

t1=t(t<1);
t2=t(t>=1);
wn=10*randn(size(t1));
wn1=10*randn(size(t2));
%  i want to create   signal which consist of sinusoidal components in
%  addtiive of white noise ,  frequencies are defined in time as
x=25*sin(2*pi*23*t(t<1))+20*cos(2*pi*24*t(t<1))+24*sin(2*pi*22*t(t<1))+wn;
y=21*sin(2*pi*20*t(t>=1))+26*cos(2*pi*17*t(t>=1))+21*sin(2*pi*29*t(t>=1))+wn1;
z=[x';y'];
plot(t',z);
```

Comment: your problem is then `randn()` at the end of your x,y definition. You are trying to add arrays of different dimension. size(t) results in another value than `t(t<1)` or `t(t>1)`.

Comment: aa so i should  define it before

Comment: Either you could use `randn(size(t(t<1)))` or you could ignore it and after you define `z` do `z=z+10*randn(size(t))`. Those should both work

Comment: Another tiny error is that you "delete" your `t==1` You must use either `t(t<=1)` in x or `t(t>=1)` in y definition or the dimension of z and t won't be the same

Comment: i have updated please see

Comment: Now i think it should work. Any further questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem is then `randn()` at the end of your x,y definition. You are trying to add arrays of different dimension. `size(t)` results in another value than `t(t<1)` or `t(t>1)`.

Either you could use

```
x=25*sin(2*pi*23*t(t<1))+20*cos(2*pi*24*t(t<1))+24*sin(2*pi*22*t(t<1))+10*randn(size(t(t<1)));
y=21*sin(2*pi*20*t(t>=1))+26*cos(2*pi*17*t(t>=1))+21*sin(2*pi*29*t(t>=1))+10*randn(size(t(t>=1)));
```

or you could ignore it and after you define `z` do:

```
x=25*sin(2*pi*23*t(t<1))+20*cos(2*pi*24*t(t<1))+24*sin(2*pi*22*t(t<1));
y=21*sin(2*pi*20*t(t>=1))+26*cos(2*pi*17*t(t>=1))+21*sin(2*pi*29*t(t>=1));
z= [x,y];
z=z+10*randn(size(t));
```

Those should both work. 
Another tiny error is that you "delete" your `t==1` You must use either `t(t<=1)` in x or `t(t>=1)` in y definition or the dimension of z and t won't be the same

Comment: sorry @datodatuashvili I don't get what you mean. I see more optimal version... this is just meant as one way how to solve it... and why thanks in advance? you still got a question concerning this problem?

Comment: no no, :D :D sorry for misunderstanding, when i said  i see more optimal version i meant your code, instead of generate white noise two times, in your code it is generated one time, that is what i meant

Answer (score 2):

I separated out the "x=" line to isolate the error:

```
x1 = 25*sin(2*pi*23*t(t<1));
x2 = 20*cos(2*pi*24*t(t<1));
x3 = 24*sin(2*pi*22*t(t<1));
x4 = 10*randn(size(t(t<1)));
```

Now x1, x2, x3 and x4 are the same size. You can only sum arrays of the same size. Now this code will not error:

```
>> x = [x1 + x2 + x3 + x4];
>> plot(t, x)
```

Then repeat for y, replacing "less than 1" with "greater than or equal to 1".

Comment: Your edited code works without error. Is there still a problem?

Comment: @danny your definition of x at the end is wrong i think. You are just adding 3 sine waves and then at the end you add noise of the size of t. He wants the noise in his signal which is [x,y].

Comment: @danny sorry to bother you again but now your solution is right and working, but the text between your code blocks is just wrong, because it is still refering to your old solution